# Constant single using the hex memory value in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

How can I make a single constant based on a hex value where that hex value is an unsigned integer and the raw memory for the single. I would like to do something like this but it doesn't compile and this will try and cast the hex value to a single and then store the result of that cast instead of storing hex value itself:

```
LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO = Single($80800000);
```

I get a "Invalid Typecast" error.

For example:

The single value for 1 is stored as $3F800000 in memory. I would like to be able to create a `const` that lets me set the value using $3F800000 instead of 1.

I have also tried other variations such as this without luck:

```
LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO = PSingle(@$80800000)^;
```

**Background**

I have a method that I use to get the next smallest single when provided with a single value:

```
type
  PInt32 = ^Int32;

function NextBefore(const aValue: Single): Single;
var
  int32Value: Int32;
begin
  // this function ignores special values nan/inf
  int32Value := PInt32(@aValue)^;
  if (UInt32(int32Value) = $80000000) or (int32Value = 0) then
  begin
    // special handling needed for -0 and 0. We need to go to the smallest
    // negative number.
    int32Value := $80800000;
  end
  else
  begin
    if int32Value >= 0 then
      Dec(int32Value)
    else
      Inc(int32Value);
  end;
  Result := PSingle(@int32Value)^;
end;
```

This is really useful because we use vector operations that can only do a > or < so we use it to do the equivalent of a >= and a <=. We often check against 0. So where we need get all of the data >= 0 we do something like this:

```
MyVector.ThresholdGT(NextBefore(0));
```

It would be nicer to provide the other developers with a constant for these types of operations. Trying to use the PSingle format below won't work because the number is not a variable.

Comment: I think your code has undefined behavior if you pass in a `Single` value that exceed the bounds of `Int32`. Why are you reinterpreting the `Single` bits as `Int32` bits at all?  You are performing integer math, not floating-point math. Is that what you really want? The largest positive and negative `Single` values are far far larger than the largest positive and negative `Int32` values. The `System.Math` unit has `MinSingle` and `MaxSingle` constants.

Comment: @remy That's exactly why it's not working. I will amend the question. I need the single value as it would be represented in memory.

Comment: But WHY? What are you really trying to solve? Can you provide examples? Why not just do something more like this? `if (aValue = -0.0) or (aValue = 0.0) then Result := -WhateverValueYouWant else if (aValue > 0.0) then Result := aValue - 1.0 else Value := aValue + 1.0 end;`

Comment: @remy I would like to simulate a >= by just doing a >. In order to do that I need a number that is just slightly smaller than the number that I am checking. I can get that with nextbefore but I can't use nextbefore in a const. I know that the hex value for that number is $80800000. If I use a var constant that can be assigned at runtime then other people can change it by accident. I can use nextbefore(0) in code but other developers don't always understand what that is.

Comment: @remy The vector operations don't have a >=, they only have a >

Comment: Pretty hard to do this as a constant. Why do you need it to be a constant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't have to put it as a constant. I can do a function or a writable typed constant. I thought it would be easy to create a constant until I tried. Then I asked the question because I thought it would be interesting to know if it's possible. It's basically a constant where you set the underlying data.

Comment: Delphi is really picky about floating point constant expressions.

Comment: Won't this do the job for you?:`const iLARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO : Int32 = $80800000; var LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO : Single absolute iLARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO;`

Comment: Trying to change the value of `LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO` will give a compiler error `Left side cannot be assigned to`.

Comment: @LURD That would actually work. It prevents people changing the value and can be used in code.

Comment: It's not very pretty though. Surely you can do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to do this cleanly with the constraints of the language. Perhaps the best that you can do is to make a variant record type that has both integer and single fields overlapped.

```
type
  TSingleIntegerVariantRec = record
    case Integer of
      0: (I: Integer);
      1: (S: Single);
  end;
```

Once you have that type available you can declare typed constants using the integer field, but then read the single field.

```
const
  LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO: TSingleIntegerVariantRec = (I: $80800000);
.... 
MyVector.ThresholdGT(LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO.S);
```

If you want to add an extra nuance you could implement an implicit cast operator to `Single` which would allow you to omit the `.S`. If you made that operator inline then I suspect the emitted code would be very efficient.

This does what you ask, but I wouldn't claim that it was very elegant. We're I you I would move the code to use the next value down into the library function so that you can pass `0` and shield the consumer of the library from these implementation details.

In other words you would add a `ThresholdGTequal` method that was implemented like this:

```
procedure TMyVector.ThresholdGTequal(const Value: Single);
begin
  ThresholdGT(NextBefore(Value));
end;
```

Then the consumers of this code simply write:

```
MyVector.ThresholdGTequal(0);
```

and remain oblivious to all of the gnarly implementation details.

Comment: Unfortunately the [Intel IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504068) only have a Threshold_GT operation and not a Threshold_GTEqual one. Another enhancement to your solution would be to add `class operator Implicit(a: TSingleIntegerVariantRec): Single;` operator overload which would remove the need for the `.S`.

Comment: @Graymatter So you would implement `Threshold_GTEqual(Value)` by calling `Threshold_GT(NextBefore(Value))`. That shields the caller from all of this. That's surely what you are expected to do. I think you are making life far too hard for yourself by attempting such nasty workarounds.

Comment: I see what you mean. This definitely the solution that I will be using.

Answer (score 2):

In order to declare a single constant with a hex value in such a way that it cannot be altered by code, it can be done in two steps:

```
const 
  iLARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO : Int32 = $80800000; 
var 
  LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO : Single absolute iLARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO;
```

Trying to change the value of `LARGEST_SINGLE_LESS_THAN_ZERO` will give a compiler error: `Left side cannot be assigned to`.

Comment: See also [How can I make signaling NaNs easy to work with?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16252964/576719).